# How to add a product chooser to a Magento 2 widget

Tags: magento2, product, custom-field, addfield, product-chooser

I want to add product chooser field like this
[image]

I am using this code but its not working anyone please help me.

```
helper = $helper;
        $this->_allProducts = $allProducts;
        $this->_systemStore = $systemStore;
        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
        $this->timezone = $timezone;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }


    /**
     * @return Main
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     * @throws Exception
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('lofauction_product');
        $dateFormat = $this->_localeDate->getDateFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::SHORT);

        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
        //$form->setUseContainer(true);

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'options_fieldset',
            ['legend' => __('Product Information'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide fieldset-widget-options']
        );
        if ($model->getId()) {
            $fieldset->addField('auction_entity_id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'auction_entity_id']);
        }
        if (!$model->getProductId()) {
            $chooserField = $fieldset->addField(
                'options_fieldset_entity_id',
                'label',
                [
                    'name' => 'product_id',
                    'label' => __('Product'),
                    'required' => true,
                    'class' => 'widget-option',
                    'note' => __("Select a product"),
                ]
            );
            /*Add chooser helper for the field*/
            $helperData = [
                'data' => [
                    'button' => ['open' => __("Select Product...")]
                ]
            ];
            // $chooserField->setValue('product/' . $model->getProductId());
            // Fixes Require product.
            $chooserField->setValue($model->getProductId());
            $helperBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                'Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Widget\Chooser',
                '',
                $helperData
            );

            $helperBlock->setConfig($helperData)
                ->setFieldsetId($fieldset->getId())
                ->prepareElementHtml($chooserField)
                ->setValue($model->getId());
        } else {
            $fieldset->addField(
                'product_id',
                'note',
                [
                    'name' => 'product_id',
                    'label' => __('Product'),
                    'title' => __('Product'),
                    'text' => $this->helper->getProductbyId($model->getProductId())->getName()
                ]
            );
        }
```

Please help me.how can we add one product choose field..?

Answer (score 0):

In your widget.xml file for the product chooser field set the following class:

```
Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Widget\Chooser
```

That should do the trick.
Example:

```
        <parameter name="product" xsi:type="block" visible="true" required="true" sort_order="10">
            <label translate="true">Product</label>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Widget\Chooser">
                <data>
                    <item name="button" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="open" xsi:type="string">Choose Product...</item>
                    </item>
                </data>
            </block>
        </parameter>
```